# C++ -- Searching Unsorted Arrays

Tags: c++, search

I'm learning C++ and am playing around with searching/sorting algorithms.

I am trying to do binary search on an unsorted list of items and return the original array index. I have to sort it first, so to preserve the original indices, I created a 2D array, put the data in the first column and the original indices in the second. (I pared it down a little, which is why I had to put //insert data items here.)

```
template <class TYPE>
int SomeClass<TYPE>::find(TYPE data)
{
    TYPE(*ary)[2] = new TYPE[size()][2];

    for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++)
    {
        ary[i][0] = //insert data items here;
        ary[i][1] = i;
    }
    //reading the data items and indexes into the new 2D array works 

    someSort(ary, size());
    return bsearch(ary, 0, size()-1, data);
}
```

Assume you have some sorting algorithm. As an example, I'll just put bubble sort below because it doesn't take up much space to write.

```
template <class DT>
void SomeClass<TYPE>::someSort(TYPE A[][2], int n)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n- 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n- i - 1; j++)
        {
            if (A[j] > A[j + 1])
                swap(&A[j][0], &A[j + 1][0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Alright, so my question is how would you modify binary search for a 2D array and return the original value (which is in the second slot of the array)? (Feel free to modify my sorting example, too, in case there are issues there.)

```
template <class TYPE>
int SomeClass<TYPE>::bsearch(TYPE A[][2], int left, int right, TYPE data)
{
    while (right>= left)
    {
        int mid = left + (right+ left) / 2;

        if (A[mid][0] == data)
            return A[mid][1];

        if (A[mid][0] > data)
            right= mid- 1;
        else
            left= mid+ 1; 
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're using binary search at all, especially if you're not going to save the sorted array to reuse it for more searches? Why not just do a plain linear search?

Comment: How can you determine how to partition the data in a binary search when the data is not sorted?

Comment: Warning: new expression not used to initialize `std::unique_ptr`.  (Well, it should be one.)

Comment: "I pared it down a little..." if you `std::pair`ed it you could have saved some time. Rather than a 2D array, consider making a 1D array of `std::pair<size_t, TYPE>` Sort on `TYPE` and the paired original index will automatically move with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check your binary search implementation, as it's not correct. Here's improved version:

```
template <class TYPE>
int SomeClass<TYPE>::bsearch(TYPE A[][2], int left, int right, TYPE data)
{
    while (right>= left)
    {
        int mid = left + (right - left) / 2; // <== corrected here.

        if (A[mid][0] == data)
            return A[mid][1];

        if (A[mid][0] > data)
            right= mid- 1;
        else
            left= mid+ 1; 
    }
    return -1;
}
```

While learning it's better to code algorithms manually, but you should know that C++ provides implementation for common algorithms like binary search or quick/merge sort.

For example, you could define your value-pair `struct vp` that holds value and position in original array:

```
struct vp
{
    TYPE val;
    int pos;
    bool operator<(const vp& vp) const {
        return val < vp.val;
    }
    static bool cmp(TYPE b, const vp& a) {
        return b < a.val;
    }
};
```

then you can sort array of value-pairs using [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort):

```
vp *arr = ...
std::sort(arr, arr+size());
```

then, you can use [lower_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) or [upper_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) to do binary search in your array of value-pairs:

```
auto p = std::upper_bound(arr, arr+size(), data, vp::cmp);
```

But you'll need to interpret properly returned value to figure out if value was found in the array or not.